# Angular 2- Value not updated in the input text box but its updated if used inside the curly braces

Tags: angular, components, angular-ngmodel

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({

  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<input [(ngModel)]="name"  type="text" (input)="inputChange()">
<h3>{{name}}</h3> `
})
export class AppComponent  { 
  name = 'Apple'; 

   inputChange() {
     this.name="Zebra";

  }
}
```

here's my angular component.
I have an input box and on every key input the function "inputChange()" is called which changes my name to "Zebra",

[image: the value of name is changed but its not reflected in the textbox.]

I have to validate the user input and return certain values for which I have to call the input event everytime they write something. I want the textbox value to be same as "Zebra" as my function changes the value no matter what the user types in the textbox. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your input event to keyup

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name"  type="text" (keyup)="inputChange()">
```

Comment: Changing the event from (input) to (keyup) simply solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `inputChange()` which changes the property name to "Zebra". You already implemented Two-Way binding. So it is not necessary to call an event function.

Change this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name"  type="text" (input)="inputChange()">
```

to

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name"  type="text">
```

To validate the value, you have multiple options to do so.
1 of them are getting the object reference of the HTML element.

This can be done by:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name"  type="text" (input)="inputChange(myInput)" #myInput>
```

In component file:

```
inputChange(element: HTMLElement) {
     // Some sort of check
     name = element.value;
  }
```

And remove the two-way-binding of course `[(ngModel)]="name"`

Comment: Actually, as per the user input, I have to validate their input and return something. So, I still have to call an event function on every user input.